# Multi-threaded degradation of performance with newer versions of g++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++, pthreads, compiler-optimization

I've written some C++ backpropagation code which I'm running on a i9-9900K in Ubuntu 18.04.

The issue I'm seeing is that I'm getting progressively worse mulithreaded performance with newer versions of g++.

Single threaded benchmarks improve as expected with newer g++ versions:

```
g++ 4.8: 5437 cycles/s
g++ 5.5: 5929 cycles/s
g++ 6.5: 5932 cycles/s
g++ 7.4: 6117 cycles/s
g++ 8.3: 6921 cycles/s
```

Multi threaded benchmarks (14 pthreads on 8 cores) degrade significantly with newer versions:

```
g++ 4.8: 25456 cycles/s
g++ 5.5: 17212 cycles/s
g++ 6.5: 18616 cycles/s
g++ 7.4: 17054 cycles/s
g++ 8.3: 14797 cycles/s
```

I've seen similar behavior in CentOS 7.6 and Clear Linux as well.  Across all tested OS's the fastest performance came from using 14 threads with g++ 4.8.

Here are the compilation flags I'm using:
g++ -c -std=c++11 -march=native -Ofast

Am I using the wrong flags for compilation?  I’ve tried -O3 and the degradation is similar though less extreme (and slower than -Ofast)

```
g++ 4.8 -O3: 17256 cycles/s
g++ 5.5 -O3: 15129 cycles/s
g++ 6.5 -O3: 15779 cycles/s
g++ 7.4 -O3: 15736 cycles/s
g++ 8.3 -O3: 13361 cycles/s
```

I feel like I am running into a memory bandwidth issue with so many cores.  Are there any compilation options that can help with the memory pressure from so many threads?

Comment: I don't think we can answer this without seeing some code; for instance, how many threads do you have? Is your use of shared memory correct?

Answer (score 1):

Further testing revealed that the issue was related to the -march=native optimization flag.

g++ 4.8 treats the i9-9900k natively as core-avx2 which activates:
MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX, AES and PCLMUL

g++ 4.9 and greater treat the i9-9900k natively as broadwell which activates:
MOVBE, MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, POPCNT, AVX, AVX2, AES, PCLMUL, FSGSBASE, RDRND, FMA, BMI, BMI2, F16C, RDSEED, ADCX and PREFETCHW

Apparently this somehow results in over-optimization.

Removing the -march flag altogether fixed the issue. Disabling AVX also worked using -mno-avx and -mno-avx2

Comment: I've heard about this kind of problems in the past, generally caused by the usage of extremely fast instructions, that however are very taxing on the CPU, so, if executed multicore for a sustained period, they caused it throttle, thus degrading overall performance.

Comment: https://blog.cloudflare.com/on-the-dangers-of-intels-frequency-scaling/

Comment: Useful link. Thank you.